# HTML: Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I am implementing a webpage which has a navigation bar on the right panel and then left panel will display the detail (Just like facebook).

Basically, I am confused how to draw the vertical line to divide the navigation panel and the display panel.

I google this but most of the tutorial only shows how to construct a tab-like navigation bar.

Can anyone give me some idea on how to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just like facebook? Have you tried inspecting the css and html of facebook? :)

Comment: Google "CSS Floats 101". There are a lot to learn.

Comment: Yes, I think float is a better way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `border-left` on the right panel - or set a `border-right` on the left panel. Use `margin` and `padding` to adjust the placement.